# How Can I Further Simplify the InOrder code by making just one call to OutofOrder?

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, simplify

Having trouble trying to find a way to simplify the inOrder code so that it makes just one singular call to OutofOrder. I am having difficulty trying to find a way to make the call...

```
public class InOrder {
//Don't change this
public boolean OutOfOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return (n1 > n2) || (n2 > n3);
}

//The original and messy InOrder, leave this as an example of what not to do
public boolean inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
if (n2 > n1) {
  if (n3 > n2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else if (n2 == n1) {
  if (n3 == n1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
}

//The new and improved InOrder for part 5, call OutOfOrder
public boolean inOrder5a(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return true; //replace this
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to negate the result, this way:

```
public boolean inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    return !OutOfOrder(n1, n2, n3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cyril's answer, you can get a new `InOrder` by negating the logic statement in `OutOfOrder`

`OutOfOrder` says `p v q` (read: p or q)
where:

- `p` is `n1 > n2`, and
- `q` is `n2 > n3`

`~(p v q)` = `~p ^ ~q` (read: not p and not q)

So:

- `~p` is `n1 <= n2` (the opposite of `n1 > n2`), and
- `~q` is `n2 <= n3` (the opposite of `n2 > n3`)

so you could rewrite `InOrder` as

`return (n1 <= n2) && (n2 <= n3)`